# SQL Server Management Studio - SSMS doesn't show BackUp and Restore options on Tasks menu

Tags: sql-server, ssms, backup, database-migration, bacpac

I'm tying to transfer one sql database from one Azure account to another. One way to do this is documented by Microsoft here  [[Restore a Backup from a Device (SQL Server)]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-backup-from-a-device-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), where they recomend to use BackUp and Restore options, but these options don't exist in my Task Menu:

[image]

I'm using SSMS V18.8 and the databases are hosted on Azure. Both source and destination server are in two different Azure accounts. I spent a lot of hours and didn't get a solution. Neither to show the options or using another way to transfer the database.

Comment: I haven't ever used any of the Azure SQL offerings, but being PaaS, aren't the backups managed for you? If so, is it possible that they remove the ability for you to take your own backups to avoid potentially disrupting their backup chain?

Comment: I don´t think so, even when I access another database using ssms, these options aren't on menu. It seems like it is a kind of settings of ssms. But thank you @BenThul for the tip. This can be an alternative for the migration. I mean, actually, Azure offers backup management and maybe can be possible to migrate using the backup files generated om Azure.

Comment: "when I access another database using ssms" - is that database also on Azure? What if you install Developer Edition on your workstation and try to backup a database. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks @BenThul, I will try. I don´t know much about Developer Edition, but I will try it.